# What is the proper FormAssembly regex expression to accept only a specific domain?

Tags: regex, forms

I have a formassembly RFI form that I want to collect emails but also validate/accept only emails ending with a specific domain such as example@specific.domain wherein "@specific.domain" is accepted and other than this the field will prompt users to input only emails ending with @specific.domain. Can this be done? If so I appreciate any guidance.

My current setup doesn't work which is /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@bgmh.com$/

Thanks!

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@bgmh\.com$/m` - you forgot to escape the period and the multiline flag

Comment: @MonkeyZeus perfect! This worked. I didn't realize I was missing this flag.